# Two nearly same codes are giving different output in Python. Can anyone explain the reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have been trying to write a program to reverse a number in Python, but it dosen't work as expected whereas only assigning the condition to a variable, it makes the code work fine. Please explain why this happens or whether this is a bug.

I am using Python 3.10.4. The codes are given below.

This one does not work as I guess the problem is in while loop and its condition.

```
num2 = int(input("Enter the number to be reversed: "))
c = 0
rev = 0
while c!=len(str(num2)):
    n = num2%10
    rev=rev*10+n
    num2=num2//10
    c+=1
print("The reversed number is:",rev)
```

Output:

```
Enter the number to be reversed: 1568
The reversed number is: 86
```

This one does work as expected just by assigning a part of condition to a variable

```
num2 = int(input("Enter the number to be reversed: "))
c = 0
rev = 0
length = len(str(num2))
while c!=length:
    n = num2%10
    rev=rev*10+n
    num2=num2//10
    c+=1
print("The reversed number is:",rev)
```

Output:

```
Enter the number to be reversed: 1568
The reversed number is: 8651
```

Comment: The length of the number changes during the loop. It makes a difference whether you evaluate the length once before the loop or anew in each iteration…

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was stuck from nearly 4 hours because of this. Thanks for explaining and helping me out.

Comment: You can run your code in a debugger or add print statements. It'll save you the four hours next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the `while` loop is evaluated again in each iteration. Because your first version evaluates the *current* length of `num2` and you change the value inside the loop, you have a bug. Change the code so it uses a different variable (initialized as a copy of `num2`) inside the loop if you prefer this formulation for some reason; but the second version of the code is IMHO clearer as well as correct.

However, notice also that Python already knows how to reverse a string.

```
rev_num = int(str(num2)[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use simple string slicing to achive the same result

```
num_to_rev = 1568
rev_num = str(num_to_rev)[::-1]
print(rev_num)
```

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)